# VueJS - why do forEach / push and .filter return different results?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, foreach

This is more of a plain JavaScript question I guess, but why does looping through an object with a forEach loop and pushing matching items to your result array return a different result that using `.filter`?

Aren't they basically the same thing?

```
updated() {
    this.locations.forEach((loc) => {
      if (loc.fields.UserRolesPermitted.includes(this.airtableView)) {
        this.loopedLocations.push(loc);
      }
    });
    console.log(this.loopedLocations); // returns correct object, i.e. has length

    this.filteredLocations = this.locations.filter((loc) => {
      loc.fields.UserRolesPermitted.includes(this.airtableView);
    });
    console.log(this.filteredLocations); // returns empty [__ob__: Observer]
  }
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from the callback of `filter`. Either use `return` or lose the braces `{ }` and use the implicit return of arrow functions. I'm voting to close this as typo/not reproducible question

Comment: First of, **.filter()** returns-by-match - therefore you're missing a `return` statement (Or use *Implicit Return* in your Arrow function)